# How can I round double values?

Tags: vb.net

My question is the bigmac works fine when I press the bigmacadd button and minus button. But when I press the mcdouble add button, I get a bunch of numbers. How can I make it so it shows 2.50 as decimal places?

```
Public Class Form1
    Const bigmac As Decimal = 4D
    Const mcdouble As Decimal = 2.25
    Dim tax As Decimal
    Dim price As Decimal
    Dim quantity As Integer
    Dim finaltotal As Decimal

    Private Sub Btnbigmacadd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btnbigmacadd.Click
        quantity = quantity + 1
        txtquan.Text = quantity

        price += bigmac
        txtprice.Text = price

        tax = price * 0.15
        txttax.Text = tax

        finaltotal = price + tax
        txtfinaltotal.Text = finaltotal
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnbigmacminus_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnbigmacminus.Click
        quantity = quantity - 1
        txtquan.Text = quantity

        price -= bigmac
        txtprice.Text = price

        tax = price * 0.15
        txttax.Text = tax

        finaltotal = price + tax
        txtfinaltotal.Text = finaltotal
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        quantity = quantity + 1
        txtquan.Text = quantity

        price += mcdouble
        txtprice.Text = price

        tax = price * 0.15
        txttax.Text = tax

        finaltotal = price + tax
        txtfinaltotal.Text = finaltotal
     End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You need to be way more specific and need to put in some effort of your own solving the problem. What is this program doing? What are the "bunch of numbers" you are presently getting as output? What have you tried doing? What do you know so far? Plopping down some code and saying you want 2.50 as the output is not the way to go about this.

Comment: I'm guessing he's getting a total that has more just 2 decimal places, like 2.50293. If so use `txtfinaltotal.Text = Format(finaltotal,"#.00")` The 0's mean round it to two decimal places.

Comment: Also: never never **NEVER** use `Double` when working with money. Instead, when handling money (and other things where small inaccuracies in precision have meaningful consequences), you should use the `Decimal` type. It's orders of magnitude slower, but sometimes the precision matters more, and handling monetary calculations is one of those times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can round `tax` to two decimal places using the `Math.Round` method

```
tax = Math.Round(price * 0.15D, 2)
txttax.Text = tax.ToString()

finaltotal = price + tax
txtfinaltotal.Text = finaltotal.ToString()
```

If want to keep the extra decimal places in `tax` and `finaltotal`, but show only two decimal places in the text boxes, you can use the `ToString("N2")` method.

```
tax = price * 0.15D
txttax.Text = tax.ToString("N2")

finaltotal = price + tax
txtfinaltotal.Text = finaltotal.ToString("N2")
```